# Model/variable selection in binomial models for marble counts?

Tags: binomial-distribution, model-selection, aic

Thank you in advance for your help with this interesting question that has come up in my research. I changed the problem to bags/marbles to simplify.

### Problem description

There are N bags, each containing varying numbers of marbles.  These marbles can be red, blue, green, and yellow. On top of their color, these marbles may or may not be striped, and each color marble has a different *observed* fraction of striped marbles. We also know the overall observed fraction of striped marbles, aggregated over all colors.

Can we determine whether or not knowing the color compositions of the bags meaningfully enhances our predictions for the numbers of striped marbles in each bag?

The research question in other words is: does knowing the marble color counts for each bag meaningfully enhance our predictions for the number of striped marbles in each bag, or does it suffice just to know each bag’s total marble count (with no color information)?

### My approach

I believe the answer to the research question will depend on the data.  For example, if the observed fraction of striped marbles is very similar across color groups, then knowing the color information may not meaningfully enhance prediction accuracy, though it will increase model complexity.

In my current approach to answering this question, I compare the [AIC](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118856406.app5) of two models.

Model 1 predicts that the number of marbles in each bag is equally likely to be striped, with probability equal to the overall observed fraction of striped marbles across all bags. For each bag, we can calculate the likelihood of the model given the observed number of striped marbles using the [binomial likelihood function](https://sites.warnercnr.colostate.edu/gwhite/wp-content/uploads/sites/73/2017/04/BinomialLikelihood.pdf).

Model 2 predicts that the number of marbles in each bag depends on that bag’s color composition.  For each bag, I calculate the expected fraction (MLE) of striped balls in that bag using color count information for that bag combined with the observed (over all bags) probability that each given color is to be striped. Again, we calculate the likelihood of the observed number of striped marbles under this model using the binomial likelihood function, just with a different, “color adjusted”  value for p.

Model 1 has one “parameter,” which is the overall observed fraction of striped marbles. I put quotes around parameter here, because we’re not allowing this parameter to be adjusted such that likelihood is maximized.

Model 2 has four: the observed fraction of striped 1. red, 2. blue,  3. green, and 4. yellow marbles.

We can calculate the overall log likelihood of the data for each model:
log(likelihood($Bag_0$) + log(likelihood($Bag_1$) +… + log(likelihood($Bag_N$)

So we can calculate the AIC for each model, as we know the number of parameters used in each.

If I find that model 1 has the lower AIC, can I safely conclude that knowing the color compositions of the bags does not meaningfully enhances our predictions for the numbers of striped marbles in each bag?

Is there a better way to go about answering my original research question?

Edit: Example data

```
bag, color, is_striped,
1,   b,     False,
1,   b,     True,
1,   b,     True,
1,   r,     False,
1,   r,     False,
1,   y,     True,
1,   g,     False,
2,   y,     False,
2,   y,     False,
2,   y,     True,
2,   g,     True,
2,   g,     True,
3,   b,     False,
3,   b,     False,
3,   g,     False,
3,   g,     True,
4,   r,     True,
4,   b,     False,
```

Comment: Can you clarify how your observations look like? Write as an edit an example data file!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes! I updated the end of the post with a small example list of observations.  I hope this makes my question more clear.

Comment: How large is N? You could try logistic regression ...